# BigQuery - How to find count of Unique overlapping values in 1 or or more categories (Count of categorical values)?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, counting

I am very new to BigQuery and standard SQL. I might not be able to figure out the correct approach to solve a problem. Please help me out.

Please help me change this code to get the desired output.

I have a Color Column and a ID column. Example shown below:

**Color** **|** **ID** 
Blue | id_1
Blue | id_5
Blue | id_6
Blue | id_2
Blue | id_7
Green | id_1
Green | id_2
Green | id_3
Red | id_3
Red | id_5
Red | id_2
Red | id_4
Red | id_7
Yellow | id_3
Yellow | id_4

**I want a resulting output as mentioned below:**

- I want to look at how many times id_1 has repeated across multiple colors and capture the number of colors as a bucket.
- I am not looking for 'Color' names instead, i am looking at the **Number of Colors**

[Reference for input and Expected output/results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqXjx.png)

Sample output:

**Number of Brands** **||** **1 Color** **:|:** **2 Colors** **:|:** **3 Colors** **:|:** **4 Colors**
**Count of Unique Ids** **||** 1 **|** 5 **|** 1 **|** 0 **|**

Thank you for your patience and time in advance.

The difficulty I have is that there is of course overlap so a GROUP BY or a DISTINCT to continuously populate 1 Color, 2 colors, 3 colors and so on dynamically.

```
SELECT id, Color, COUNT(1) number
FROM project.dataset.table
GROUP BY id, Color
```

Comment: I believe SO is a platform to exchange ideas and solve technical challenges that we face on a daily basis. I am just requesting help and ideas towards a solution which i might not have enough experience with. Please do not use this platform to throw negative light on someone's  genuine efforts to solve an issue. Any help is greatly appreciated, valued and respected.

Comment: thank you for "fixing" your original question - it looks better now :o) just as FYI - read - [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5221944) . And NO - SO is NOT a platform to exchange ideas - this is not a forum or discussion board, but rather Question / Answer type of site. And you don't need to take comments of this type too personal especially as you are new to SO - someone has to point you into right direction - right?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Sure, Exchanging ideas being solving questions with multiple approaches. A question can be asked in various ways and the solution to it could have various approaches. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this on separate *rows* rather than columns:

```
select cnt, count(*) as num_colors
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by id
     ) i
group by cnt
order by cnt
```

If you want this by columns, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select countif(cnt = 1),
       countif(cnt = 2),
       countif(cnt = 3),
       countif(cnt = 4)
from (select id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by id
     ) i;
```

Note:  These assumes that the id/color rows are unique in the original data.  Otherwise, use `count(distinct color) as cnt`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I did not understand why we GROUP BY id_1. How can i handle this if i have 2M unique values?

Comment: @PavithraG .  . I just mistyped the name of the column.

Comment: select countif(cnt = 2),
       countif(cnt = 3), and so on... gives the corresponding overlapping values between 2 colors, 3 colors right??

Comment: It is the number of colors that a given id is assigned to.  That is how I interpret the question.

Comment: Yeah, This logic works only if IDs are unique right?

Comment: @PavithraG . . . I don't understand the comment.  Neither the color nor id is unique in your table, which is the point of this query.

Comment: Sorry, for not communicating clearly. Each color has unique IDs which appear across multiple color category. Either way, your logic helps a ton ! thank you!